# ProgrammingError: cannot cast type double precision to time without time zone

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, casting, postgresql-9.4

I have a django app with the following model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_type = models.ForeignKey(
        EventType,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        # we don't want to delete anything in the StatusType table.
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    reason_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    elapsed_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    event_at = models.DateTimeField("Event Time", blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
    object_id = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, )
    count = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rfid_tag = models.ForeignKey(Employee, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                 verbose_name='User Name')
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # for hiding from lists

    # def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    #     return self.event_type

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Events'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

While trying to run a simple migration, I keep getting this error:

```
File "/home/icar/E-Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/epicar/E-Django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type double precision to time without time zone
```

The problem I'm having with this, is I don't understand WHY it's trying to CAST the double precision to time without time zone. I don't want it to. I'm not quite sure what else to try. I have tried doing the following:

```
SELECT CAST(elapsed_time as double precision) FROM event;
```

I also tried changing the elapsed_time field to integer and got the same error (referencing integer instead of double precision). So I know it's that particular field.

I've deleted all of the migrations and tried to start fresh. That didn't work.

Any ideas?

Update: properties of elapsed field from pgadmin:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you look for this:

```
SELECT extract(epoch FROM now());
```

Comment: What is this doing exactly?

Comment: get seconds from epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00) or seconds from interval. It is only one way to case timestamp or interval to double precision

Comment: hmmm... the data going into that field is technically elapsed seconds. Would that cause it to throw the error? We're not pulling an actual timestamp. We don't want to. We want to display elapsed seconds so I can do calculations on it... in the form of simple numbers (not time fields). I know you can do calculations on time fields.

Comment: I do not use django, but looks like than now your table `event` has field `elapsed_time` as timestamp.  can you look for table desciption in psql or pgadmin?

Comment: I added an image of the properties for that field.

Comment: @ Roman Tkachuk = Thanks for your help - you got me going in the right direction to determine the problem

Comment: No problem - it very interesting to find the cause. Twice interesting when find by self

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. :) It ended up being on the Django side:

field type change:

```
elapsed_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

This took care of the conflict between Django and Postgres field types.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 09, 2017 - 16:34:59
Django version 1.9, using settings 'E-Django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

All good and up and running now.